# How to find and replace names witn numbering at the end in Notepad++?

Tags: regex, notepad++

I want to replace all similar names in text with Notepad++

```
image_1.jpg
image_2.jpg
image_3.jpg
...
image_n.jpg
```

to only one name: "image_x.jpg".

What is the simplest way to automate this task?

Comment: Is the underscore always going to be there, or is `image2.jpg` also a possibility?

Comment: Yes, `image2.jpg` is also a possibility.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Search :

```
^image_\d+\.jpg$
```

Replace with:

```
image_x.jpg
```

if the text is exactly same as it is in question, you could use:

search `_[^.]*` replace it with `_x`

**EDIT**

as OP commented `image2.jpg is also a possibility.`, the substitution can be done in:

search:

```
(image)_?(\d+)
```

replace with

```
\1_\2
```

this will change:

```
image3.jpg
image_1.jpg
```

into:

```
image_1.jpg
image_3.jpg
```

if you want to have a fixed name:

replace with:

```
\1_x
```

Note, if notepad++ use `$` to reference group match, use  `$1_$2`

Comment: FYI - Be sure to select `Regular expression` under `Search Mode` on the `Replace` tab :)

Answer (score 3):

Regex : `image_\d+\.jpg`

Replacement : `image_x.jpg`[image]

Comment: is there a way to add exceptions, for example: from `image_25 to image_36` and `image_46 to image_53`?

Comment: In regexes the notion of `range` is limited, for instance you can do `[1-6]` which means `1 to 6` but `[21-57]` means `2, or 1 to 5, or 7` so you need to build a regex with that. For the case `image_25 to image_36` you can do `image_(?:2[5-9]|3[0-6])\.jpg`, `2[5-9]|3[0-6]` means `2 followed by 5 to 9 (25-29)` or `3 followed by 0 to 6 (30-36)`.